# Remove and replace an external system with salesforce

Tags: apex, managed-package, integration

I am working on a assignment where i am required to remove an external system and replace it with salesforce.
The external system has an integration with salesforce using a managed package which must also be phased out. Based on my research all that i can do is identify the dependencies and if they are unmanaged then they can be replaced with some new code and if it is managed then there's nothing that can be done.
Also, for customizations involving managed package objects i'm using debug logs to check what goes on once a transaction has been triggered and i think that's the only way do let me know if you think otherwise. Can anyone provide me with tips, thoughts, best practices and considerations that must be taken to start this activity?

Comment: Can you add some details about the external system? Which system is that? Is it an inhouse system or a cloud?

Answer (score 2):

This is a very broad question and will require insight into your complete setup. I am sure you have answers of all these questions already.

- What is the role of the other system? Is it a warehouse? Is it CRM, is it a CPQ?
- Who uses that system? Can you migrate them to Salesforce? or is it just an integrated system?
- Can Salesforce fulfill all tasks done in the external system, Salesforce being a cloud system with limits?
- Any downstream integration which integrates with the external system.
- Is that system has it own set of tools other packages. Do you need to migrate those?

---

Coming to the managed package questions.

**Is it a managed system/predeveloped solution?**

If it is a managed system like Zuora or Remedy and the package is specifically built to integrate with that system then you will have a huge task at hand where you have to analyse all the functionalities and replicate them.

You won't be able to do it via just debug logs and will require a product owner for that system who knows the functionalities. It is going to be difficult to know the inner workings and would be difficult to achieve this with even 30-60% of the functionality of the current system.

**Is it an in-house developed system?**

In this case, you will still have to do the functionality mapping but the tasks are going to be a little easier because you will have access to working of the system.

This is not a comprehensive list, it takes a lot to change a system but it should be a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers Manjit. As you've said i have answers to the questions mentioned . Regarding the questions you had it's an appexchange package(name not revealed for confidentiality) that we are trying to replace with an in house system based on sfdc which can aggregate data from other systems and store it in sfdc.